# How to install a plugin on xl-release?

Tags: plugins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, ca-lisa, xlrelease

I have downloaded CA-LISA plugin from https://xebialabs.com/plugins/ and have received both .zip and .jar files. I am now stuck at installing the plugin. What are the steps to install the plugins manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install simply place the plugin in the **< XL_RELEASE >/plugins** directory, then restart XL Release.  You will then have the ability to create the appropriate tasks.  Please let me know if this helps, or if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a doubt. I happened to download ".zip" as well as ".jar" files. Which of them is actually required ?

Comment: You should put the ".jar" file into the "<XL_RELEASE>/plugins" folder. I think the ".zip" file just contains source files of the plugin.